# Why is Spring Cassandra not using the Values set in @Table with Scala?

Tags: spring, scala, cassandra

I have the following code...

```
@Table(keyspace = "ks", name="otherThing" )
class Thing extends Serializable{
  ...
}
```

However when I run...

```
repo.findAll()
```

I get an error that looks like it isn't using the values I provided...

> Query; CQL [SELECT * FROM Thing;]; unconfigured table Thing

I would expect

```
Select * from ks.otherThing;
```

What am I missing?

**Update**

I tried converting to the following Pojo

```
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.Table;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.PrimaryKey;
@Table( keyspace="ks", name="otherThing" )
public class Thing implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

And my repo is pretty simple...

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ThingRepository extends CassandraRepository<Thing, ThingId> { }
```

but

```
thingRepo.findAll();
```

gives...

> Query; CQL [SELECT * FROM thing;]; unconfigured table thing

Comment: interesting... in datastax driver 3.x it worked just fine: https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/07/using-object-mapper-scala. Driver 4.x is better, but doesn't work with Scala yet :-(

Comment: @AlexOtt Uh oh so this might be a Spring Bug?

Comment: Maybe, I’m not sure - is it runtime annotation or compile time? I’m not the Spring person...

Comment: Well I tried converting it over to Java and I am getting the same results I will post more in the question

Answer (score 0):

So the mistake I made was trying to do this with a connection that was set up using my company's spring autoconfig. This allowed me to configure the connection via `application.properties`. I noticed that the keyspace was previously declared there so I went back and changed my domain object to...

```
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Table

@Table("otherThing" )
class Thing extends Serializable{
  ...
}
```

Now it is working. Leaving this answer up in case others get confused.